# How to Control the Temperature of Heating element using its resistance

Tags: resistors, pcb-design, temperature

In my test of a thin Film heater. I derived its Temperature coefficient of Resistance. This alpha number symbolizes the resistance change factor per degree of temperature change.
My question is, Is there any setup out there that can use the change in resistance at varying temperature to control the heater.

I am looking for a circuit that could do this. Measure the resistance of the operating heater and stop it at a set resistance.

---

@ MKeith, 
I meant, just knowing the R does me no good if I cannot use it to keep the temperature at the point I want it to be.

I want to keep track of the increase in resistance (The resistance of our heaters increases at a certain rate with increase in temperature of the heater). So keeping this in mind, I want to then control the heater with the resistance.

Say I want the heater to stop at 100degC and the resistance will go from A to B at that temperature, I need ways to use this resistance B to control this heater. If I need the heater to go to another temperature, all I will do is adjust my setting to get this. Basically R is serving as temperature control instead of thermistors or RTDs.

Comment: Are you asking for someone to design a circuit for you?

Comment: No I am asking for advice on if there is anything on the market that could  do this  and if not a pointer in the right direction to achieve this will help.

Comment: My main interest was in finding alternatives and  removing the temperature sensor (e.g. RTD, thermocouple). Along with reducing system components and sources of failure. 

In a nutshell, why can't the resistance of the heating element itself be used in a closed loop system to turn the heater on and off?

Comment: Can you calculate the accuracy of such a method? I doubt it would be sufficient for somewhat precise control.

Comment: I have done extensive tests to derive the alpha number for our heater(Tin Oxide thin film heater). It is accurate to withing a few degrees. I am not looking for precision at the moment.

Comment: So the only thing you need is a way to measure the current and feed it back to your controller.

Comment: So you may have \$\alpha\$ correct for this heater, but what about 1 produced 3 months from now? That being said, a small shunt is all you need across the power and there are ICs designed to amplify the shunt to a voltage that you can use, they are cheep. This sounds like it would not require to much trouble if it is already a digital system. If it is analog/mechanical it may be a bit harder.

Comment: The alpha is constant for our heater. It is technology and product dependent and does not change because the heater is built with the same thin film. MadHatter, please explain a little bit more on that idea.

Comment: Solution 1: Drive the heating element with a constant current. Measure the voltage across the element. Use V=IR to solve for R. Solution 2: Drive the heating element with a precise regulated voltage. Use a shunt + amplifier to measure the current. Use V = IR. Solution 3: use an unregulated supply to drive the heating element. Measure both input voltage and current accurately. Use V=IR.

Comment: Knowing the R is of no help, I need to set up a control using this R. Basically a "PID that uses this R  feedback to control temperature" is what I need.

Comment: Are you actually wanting to keep the heater powered at the set-point once it's reached or just deactivate to be reset some time later manually. It's not clear in your question.

Comment: Keep it powered for varying amount of time.

Comment: You want to use a PID to control R. But you say knowing R is of no use. Or do I misunderstand?

Answer (score 4):

The circuit is relatively simple.  It creates signals for the voltage across and the current thru the resistance.  These are then sampled by a microcontroller, that performs all the control loop functions.

It takes a divide of the voltage by the current, then a table lookup, to get the parameter you are trying to control.  That is very difficult and error prone to do in analog hardware, but not much of a problem with the right microcontroller.  You want to run the control loop 20-50 times faster than the first time constant of the heater.  You haven't said how big the heater is, but it's unlikely you need to go faster than 10 ms per iteration, even for a relatively small heater.  Even 1 ms per iteration is a very long time for a microcontroller.  For example, a dsPIC 33E can do 70,000 instructions in that time.  To put this in perspective, it only take 18 instructions to divide a 32 bit number by a 16 bit number.

The tricky part will be the analog circuit to deliver a good measure of effective voltage and current.  PWM is the obvious way to control the heater since it's efficient, but having full on/off pulses going into the heating element will make it difficult to take meaningful measurements.

If you're clever, you take the A/D readings synchronous to the PWM right before the pulse shuts off.  You grab the instantaneous voltage and current when the heating element is full on, then do the divide to get resistance and a lookup to get temperature.

If that sounds like it's beyond you, then it's probably better to filter the pulses before they get to the heater.  A inductor in series, then a large cap across the heater will smooth out the ripples, hopefully to the point where the averages are valid measurements.  In that case you want to run the PWM as fast as you can to get the desired resolution, like a few 100 kHz.  If you're doing the synchronous measurements, you want to run the PWM slower, like maybe just above the audible range.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Maybe I should have clarified the kind of heater. I am looking for a basic template that will be applicable to different sizes and resistances of the heaters. The heaters are of varying sizes and resistances but they all have one thing in common; they were all built using Thin film Tin Oxide deposited on substrates ranging from Alumina to Aluminium Oxide to Glass Ceramic and Stainless Steel. My control at the moment is basic SSR and PID contraption that monitors the temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Why not separate the heating and measurement functions?

You say you have an SSR PID controller, great. Now you need a circuit which will measure the temperature of the heating element, as an input to the PID controller.

If the resistance of the heating element is proportional to temperature, you should be able to measure it. Either while the heating current is on, by measuring the current and voltage (with a 4-wire resistance measuring setup to eliminate the leads) or when it's off, with a small current source that doesn't cause much heating.

In either case you'll want to do this with a microcontroller, not an all-analogue circuit. The microcontroller could store the calibration information about the R/T characteristics of each individual heater.

As an example of a similar problem and solution, I believe some soldering irons have/had two different metals for their power leads, forming a thermocouple right at the heating tip. The iron controller would read this thermocouple voltage between heating pulses and adjust the power accordingly. So only two wires for heating and sensing.

Comment: "Now you need a circuit which will measure the temperature of the heating element, as an input to the PID controller." This is how I control it at the moment. I use Thermocouples placed onto the heaters surface to measure the temperature and provide and input to the PID. I just need to have alternative to this. Eliminate the use of TC and find a way to feed a resistance input to control the heating.

Comment: Right. So keep the existing controller and find a way to a) measure temperature using resistance, and b) feed this to the PID. It might work to just measure current through and voltage across the heating element. Have your microcontroller average over the middle half of a single heating pulse, and supply that as a voltage output for the PID controller to read.